# Program for Blinking led quickly for some time and then slowly on Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno

I am new to Arduino,i want my led to blink 5 time quickly for time period 1s and then slowly for time period 4s, i tried like this,

```
void setup()
{ 
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    int n=1;
    while (n<=5) 
    {
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);
        delay(500);
    }

    while (n<=10)
    {
        digitalWrite (13, HIGH);
        delay (2000) ;
        digitalWrite(13, LOW) ;
        delay(2000) ;
    }
```

But it's not working, please help me to fix it. Thanks

Comment: If you're going to continue to use this site please: 1) properly indent your code, 2) make your question very clear, for example, **what** is not working?

Comment: This question has no connection to the C language. Please remove the C tag.

Comment: You've written an infinite loop.  In your `while` loops add `n++` to the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating 'n' inside your while loop

```
void setup()
{ 
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    int n=1;
    while(n++ <= 5) 
    {
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);
        delay(500);
    }

    while(n++ <= 10)
    {
        digitalWrite (13, HIGH);
        delay (2000) ;
        digitalWrite(13, LOW) ;
        delay(2000) ;
    }
}
```

This should now work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has infinite loops. Since you are just counting from 1 to 5 or 10, why not make them `for` loops?

```
void setup()
{ 
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    int n;
    for (n = 1; n <= 5; n++)
    {
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);
        delay(500);
    }

    for (n = 1; n <= 10; n++)
    {
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        delay(2000);
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);
        delay(2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it sir